# I want buttons that shows certain types of images on html

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

I want to create a portfolio, but I'm having troubles with the buttons to show the images..

I don't know why it doesn't have the bottom line, and I want to set height of the boxes.

This is my code

```js
    function showImg()
{
var obj=document.getElementById('Picture1');
obj.className = 'show';
}
```

```css
.button{
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

.button .show{display:block;}
.button .hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="button">
       
        <img id="all" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item"/>
        <input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "ALL">
  
        <img id="diseño" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "DESIGN">
  
        <img id="web" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "WEB">
   
        <img id="media" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" onclick = "showImg()" value= "MEDIA"> 
             
    </div>
```

Comment: Have have no id of Picture1, thats the images source

Comment: You don't have element with Picture1 ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling the correct id before you change the classname. I suggest the following!

```
function showImg(imageID) {
   if(document.getElementById(imageID).className !== "show"){
      document.getElementById(imageID).className = "show"
   } else {
      document.getElementById(imageID).className = "hide"
    }
}
```

And call them like this

```
<img id="all" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item"/>
<input type="button" onclick = "showImg('all')" value= "ALL">
```

Also unless your inputs are in a form I think this is best practice.

```
<button type="button" onclick = "showImg('all')" value= "ALL">
```

The result would look like this:

```js
function showImg(imageID) {
   if(document.getElementById(imageID).className !== "show"){
      document.getElementById(imageID).className = "show"
   } else {
      document.getElementById(imageID).className = "hide"
    }
}
```

```css
.button{
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 40%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
}

.button .show{display:block;}
.button .hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="button">
       
        <img id="all" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item"/>
        <input type="button" onclick = "showImg('all')" value= "ALL">
  
        <img id="diseño" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" onclick = "showImg('diseño')" value= "DESIGN">
  
        <img id="web" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" onclick = "showImg('web')" value= "WEB">
   
        <img id="media" src="Picture1.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" onclick = "showImg('media')" value= "MEDIA"> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Now it works perfect. but it uses some jquery. let me know if you are not using it and not feeling good about jquery and I'll write the code in javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('input:button').click(function(){
    if($('img').hasClass("show")){
     $('img').removeClass("show","hide").addClass("hide");
     }
   var  parentGet =$(this).attr("value");
    parentGet = "img#"+parentGet.toLowerCase(); $(parentGet).addClass("show").removeClass("hide");
  });
});
```

```css
.button{
  padding: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  width: 40%;
  position:relative;
  margin: auto;
/*   display: flex; */
/*   flex-direction: row; */
  justify-content: center;
/*     display: -webkit-box; */
/*     display: -moz-box; */
/*     display: -ms-flexbox; */
/*     display: -webkit-flex; */
}
.button img{
  width:300px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
}

.button .show{display:block;}
.button .hide{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
       
        <img id="all" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/vbm4-AyA86o/hqdefault.jpg" class="hide flex-item"/>
        <input type="button" value= "ALL">
  
        <img id="design" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/cargaze/image/upload/v1479932866/KTM-RC390-2016_ssv5c8.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" value= "DESIGN">
  
        <img id="web" src="https://media.zigcdn.com/media/content/2016/Feb/bike-of-the-year-pulsar-rs200-m_720x540.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" value= "WEB">
   
        <img id="media" src="https://media.zigcdn.com/media/content/2015/Dec/new-bike-2016-pic-image-photo-hero-hx250r-30122015-m1_720x540.jpg" class="hide flex-item">
        <input type="button" value= "MEDIA"> 
             
    </div>
```

Comment: I can accept just one answer, can't upvote because of my badges, that's why I commented it works, so other people can use it and upvote...

Comment: oh. you can accept new answer same as you have accepted previous one if you click on the checkmark. the previous one gets unaccepted automatically. Most of the people really don't read comments, they just try the accepted answer.